# How to apply classes based on the open linked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My sidebar menu has the ability to expand and reveal the subsections of a section as shown below. The *open* section has the `open active` class and the clicked link has the `active` class.

All of my links has a different `#url`.So this will determine the classes.

How can I automatically place the `open active` and `active` classes based on the opened link? I can also use PHP.

```
<ul class="menu-items scroll-content">
<li class="open active">
    <a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">first section</span>
<span class="open arrow"></span></a>
<span class="icon-thumbnail">LV</span>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="page.php#first1">First Section 1</a>
            <span class="icon-thumbnail">au</span>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="page.php#first2">First Section 2</a>
            <span class="icon-thumbnail">ou</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">Second section</span>
<span class="arrow"></span></a>
<span class="icon-thumbnail">LV</span>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="">
            <a href="secondpage.php#second1">Second Section 1</a>
            <span class="icon-thumbnail">au</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="">
            <a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">first section</span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="">
                            <a href="page.php#first1">First Section 1</a>
                            <span class="icon-thumbnail">au</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                            <a href="page.php#first2">First Section 2</a>
                            <span class="icon-thumbnail">ou</span>
                    </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="">
            <a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">Second section</span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="">
                            <a href="secondpage.php#second1">Second Section 1</a>
                            <span class="icon-thumbnail">au</span>
                    </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var href = location.pathname+location.hash;

$('.sub-menu > li > a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == href) {
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().parent().parent('li').addClass('open active');
    }
});
```

Comment: it work, thank you! I have made one addition, can you guide me on this? I have added `<span class="open arrow"></span>` on the section li. when a section link it is clicked it must get the class `open arrow`

Comment: Wait a bit. I need to check it.

Comment: Add `$('li.open').children('a').find('span.arrow').addClass('open');` after `$(this).parent().parent().parent('li').addClass('open active');`